# QTcpSocket listen

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

Is it possible to listen on a QTcpSocket?
I have a simple p2p connection on Tcp.
But i cannot find a way to start a QTcpSocket on a random free port. Should i use a QTcpServer for it, or is that a little overkill for only 1 connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for listening on a port you have to use QTcpServer, checkout the socket examples.